# How to add a new module position in Joomla 2.5?

Tags: joomla2.5

How to add a new module position in Joomla 2.5?

I want to add a new module position in one template, but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add new module position in your template, you need to add position in the `templateDetails.xml` and then in your `index.php` add that position where you want to show your  module.

And after that in module manager select that position you have added for that module and check it.

For example:

- In `templatedetails.xml`, locate the `<positions></positions>` start and end tags, then add inside:

  ```
  <position>newposition</position>
  ```
- In `index.php`, locate the place in the template where you wish to put the new position and insert:

  ```
  <jdoc:include type="modules" name="newposition" />
  ```

For more details you can check this link:

- [How do you add a new module position?](http://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_add_a_new_module_position%3f)

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you're doing it in some dark and dirty place, where you can't use  directives (or shouldn't), 
that's the simpliest way:

```
   <?php
    jimport( 'joomla.application.module.helper' );
    $modules = JModuleHelper::getModules( 'your_position_name_that_you_just_enter_in_admin_ui' );
    foreach($modules as $mod )
    {
        //var_dump($mod);
        echo JModuleHelper::renderModule( $mod );
    }
   ?>
```